# how can I create simple web page to display jersey web service results?

Tags: web-services, jsp, servlets, jersey

I have followed [this tutorial](http://avilyne.com/?p=105) to create a simple Rest client for Android and Tomcat web service. My question is how can I create a simple web page to display web service data from the postPerson method? Do I have to save the person to a database first? Can I just create a simple JSP file? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey 1.x / 2.x offers a way how to achieve this (via it's MVC extensions). Refer to the documentation/samples for more information:

#### Jersey 1.x

- [MVCJ](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj) blog entry discussing template processing
- [bookstore](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey/samples/bookstore) sample that uses this feature

#### Jersey 2.x

- [MVC](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html) chapter in documentation
- same [bookstore-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bookstore-webapp) sample migrated to Jersey 2.x